# GMail stops sending push notification

Tags: gmail-api

I've configured the push notifications following [this guide](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/guides/push) and when calling the [watch](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/v1/reference/users/watch) endpoint I get an expiration of about one week.

During this period I expect to receive notification to the Pub/Sub topic I've configured without the need to call the `watch` endpoint some time before the expiration date.

However what happens is that after about one day I'm not receiving notifications anymore and calling the `watch` endpoint doesn't help.

Why GMail has stopped to send notification to the subscription endpoint?

Comment: Can you add any details like: code used, error problem encountered? [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) Show the community what you have tried.

Comment: I've just followed exactly the [Google Push notifications guide] (https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/guides/push), so they're just a set of API calls. Google response is always 200 so there are no errors but after some time I no longer receive the webhooks to the specified endpoint.

Comment: Hi, did you manage to fix your issue? We are experiencing the same issue despite the fact we renew the subscription (call to `watch`) everyday.
Sometimes we stop receiving notifications between 2 renewal and so customers don't receive messages during that time.

Answer (score 1):

Gmail Pub/Sub notification subscriptions expire in 7 days, you have to call `watch()` again to renew your subscription.

https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/guides/push#renewing_mailbox_watch

Maybe that's the issue.